# File server monitoring in AD

Tags: filesystems, active-directory

I was asked to find a way to monitor changes (modification, renaming, deletion, moving) of files in specific folders on the company's shared file server (simple windows shared directory)
What I'd like to know now is how to find out the name/IP of the user/computer who made these changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to enable the Audit Object Access auditing policy for that server in Group Policy 
:

`Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy`

To audit unauthorized access, enable Failure auditing.

To audit who is accessing, enable Success auditing.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Auditing_Windows_Server_2008_File_and_Folder_Access

You can also right-click on any folder, under the Security tab, choose Advanced, then choose the Auditing tab.

You can then add groups of users to audit, and choose what actions you'd like to monitor.

All log information for moves, copies, deletes, etc, will be in the Security log in the server's Event Viewer.

Comment: Its better to use any auditing tool for this or should i proceed with this procedure only as I am beginner on this this plz guide for the same